# React form inside popup doesn’t clear input values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm using [framework7](https://framework7.io/react/) for this
Created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/f7-popup-bugs-forked-owfhp

From a parent file and a child component (Popup). i’m creating a simple submit form.
Form state is cleared after submission, but inside the Popup data still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/f7-popup-bugs-forked-uu22k?file=/src/App.js

I just edited these:

```
const [form, setFormValues] = useState({ name: "", email: "" });

const closePopup = () => {
  setOpened(false);
  setFormValues({ name: "", email: "" });
};
```

Comment: Thanks it's working, but if I'd like to set state object empty (const [form, setFormValues] = useState({});) and on change input state will add target input and value??

Comment: Or it's better to define all form input fields in state? like you did...

Comment: @VitalieJalbu  There is another way, if you really want to set state object empty, then you can write the value prop in ListInput component like this: ```value={data?.name || ""}```.  I edited the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/f7-popup-bugs-forked-78lhq?file=/src/DemoPopup.js